# Difference between mixing ratio and mole fraction

Tags: atmospheric-science, meteorology

I have been reading 'The Atmosphere of Venus' by V.I. Moroz which is available [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1981SSRv...29....3M). I am confused about the term 'mixing ratio' which is used on discussions in chemical composition.

From what I understand, mixing ratio of ith component of air is the ratio of number density of ith component to the total number density of air. As per the relation between number density and molar concentration given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_density#Molar_concentration), shouldn't mixing ratio of a component be the same as it's mole fraction?

Moreover, is there any difference between mixing ratio and volume mixing ratio?

Comment: (See also [EarthScience.SE] Stack Exchange)

Comment: Should I shift my question there?

Comment: The question is on-topic both here and there.  Let's see if you get any good answer here.  If you don't get any answers after several days, you could flag for migration.

Comment: In my opinion, the meteorologists should have taken more chemistry classes.

Answer (score 2):

Mole fraction is the amount of a constituent divided by the total amount of all constituents in a mixture:

$x_i = \frac{n_i}{n_{tot}}$

Mixing ratio is the amount of a constituent divided by the total amount of all *other* constituents in a mixture:

$x_i = \frac{n_i}{n_{tot}-n_i}$

So, if $n_i$ is much smaller than $n_{tot}$ (e.g. trace gases in the atmosphere), the mixing ratio is almost identical to the mole fraction.

Answer (score 1):

### mixing ration vs. fraction

When we calculate the molar(/mass/volume) **fraction** ($x_i$), we divide by the total molar amount(/mass/volume). In contrast, the **mixing ration** ($r_i$) is calculated by dividing by the molar amount(/mass/volume) of all other components

$x_i = \frac{n_i}{n_{tot}}$

$r_i = \frac{n_i}{n_{tot} - n_i}$

However, when $n_i \ll n_{tot}$, we can assume that

$x_i = r_i$

### volume fraction vs. molar fraction

You are right if we consider the atmospheric gases to behave like ideal gases. For the ideal gas we know

$p \times V_i = n_i \times R \times T$

with the pressure $p$, the volume of species $i$ $V_i$, the molar amount of species $i$ $n_i$, the gas constant $R$ and the temperature $T$.

Applying the ideal gas law on the volume fraction $\Phi_i$ we come to the molar fraction $x_i$.

$\Phi_i = \frac{V_i}{V_{tot}} = \frac{n_i \times R \times T \times p^{-1}}{n_{tot} \times R \times T \times p^{-1}} = \frac{n_i}{n_{tot}} = x_i$

### summary

When we assume

- to nearly have an ideal gas,
- $n_i \ll n_{tot}$ and
- $V_i \ll V_{tot}$,

then the volume mixing ration approximately equals the molar fraction:

$ \frac{V_i}{V_{tot} - V_i} \approx \frac{n_i}{n_{tot}}$

Comment: Presumably that should be $V_{tot} - V_i$ in the last line?

Comment: @MJuckes : Thanks. I corrected it.